# License in Java Web Application(.war)

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a java web application(.war) that i need to be license secured.My web application is targeted to deploy on Apache Tomcat.I need License in two formats One is Trial for 15 days and Next is for Fixed Span of time and this can be for one year of greater to it also.

Any suggestions will be a start for me ..

Comment: I would start with google. E.g. http://afewguyscoding.com/2012/02/licensing-module-java/

Comment: ehm .... suggestions for what?
just put something like:
TRIAL LICENSE
--------------
< trial conditions >

and 

Fixed Span
----------

< fixed span conditions >

Comment: Check License4J (disclosure: I work for License4J)

Answer (score 2):

There are frameworks out there to do this you will have to pay if you are not an open source project.

http://www.license4j.com

https://truelicense.java.net

Generally, these can be as complex or a simple as you like. It is easy to create such a framework. The trick is implementing a protection mechanism that isn't easy to fool. Generally you would want to encrypt the 'licence' data in some form to ensure that it couldn't be easily altered.

Comment: Sir i am in need of free framework.Is there any?

Comment: Generally not. Some are free for open source projects if you follow a specific licence model but are otherwise hard to come by.